# Error with Eureka Server Cluster (peer awareness)

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

My question is about Spring Cloud Eureka: I'm trying to run Eureka Cluster (2 nodes, localhost:8761, localhost:8762),
but some errors appear:

- RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : 
  Request execution error: 
  `endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}`
- RetryableEurekaHttpClient :

  Request execution failed with message: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`
- DiscoveryClient : `DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/192.168.1.4:8761 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server`

Here are **application.yml** files:

**Server 1:**

```yaml
spring:
    profiles: eureka-peer1

server:
    port: 8761

eureka:
    instance:
        hostname: eureka-peer1
    client:
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://eureka-peer2:8762/eureka/
```

**Server 2:**

```yaml
spring:
   profiles: eureka-peer2

server:
    port: 8762

eureka:
   instance:
       hostname: eureka-peer2
   client:
       registerWithEureka: true
       fetchRegistry: true
       serviceUrl:
           defaultZone: http://eureka-peer1:8761/eureka/
```

**File /etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   eureka-peer1
127.0.0.1   eureka-peer2
```

**ErekaService1Application.java** , **ErekaService2Application.java**:

```java
package com.example.eurekaservice1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableEurekaClient
public class EurekaService1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaService1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Removing @EnableEurekaClient and setting "registerWithEureka" and "fetchRegistry" to "false" gives the same results.

Moreover, standalone mode with these properties leads to the same error:

```yaml
spring:
  profiles: eureka-peer1

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

Here is **pom.xml** file, automatically generated using start.spring.io:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-service-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka-service-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `@EnableEurekaClient` & dependency as well

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```